# Iterating through different text box in java script and assigning values

Tags: javascript

I was trying to iterate in loop through text boxes and assign values to it. I have created three array list `ids[]`,`id1s[]`,`id2s[]`.

values in `ids[]` have to be populated in the first column and its coming fine. but values in `id1s[]` and `id2[]` need to be populated in the 2nd and 3rd column. loop run 5 times. first times it populating in the first row, but from next time onward its overriding the first row.. and not coming to second row

Below is my code :--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function start()
        {
          var ids = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
          var id1s = [1,2,3,4,5];
          var id2s = [6,7,8,9,10];
          for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
            var value=ids[i];
            addrow(value);
            addData(id1s[i], id2s[i]);
          }
        }

        function addrow(value)
        {
          var test1 = value+'1';
          var test2 = value+'2';
          var TABLE = document.getElementById('tableId');
          var BODY = TABLE.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
          var TR = document.createElement('tr');
          var TD1 = document.createElement('td');
          var TD2 = document.createElement('td');
          var TD3 = document.createElement('td');
          TD1.innerHTML = value;
          TD2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='test1' value=''>";
          TD3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='test2' value=''>";
          TR.appendChild (TD1);
          TR.appendChild (TD2);
          TR.appendChild (TD3);
          BODY.appendChild(TR);
        }

        function addData(num,num1)
        {
          alert("Showing assignment of values");
          document.getElementById("test1").value=num;
          document.getElementById("test2").value=num1;
        }
      </script>
    </head>
  <body>

  <table id="tableId" border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>Variable</td> 
    <td>Value1</td>
    <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
  <button type="button" onclick="start()">Display</button>                  
  </table>

</body>
```

please suggest how to iterate through the text boxes created in 2nd and 3rd column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your addrow and  addData functions

For addrow function
You have to use the value inside test1 and test2 to form the input ids
like this

```
TD2.innerHTML ="<input type='text' id='"+ test1 + "' value=''>";
TD3.innerHTML ="<input type='text' id='"+ test2 + "' value=''>";
```

for addData function bring in the 'value' variable as a parameter
and change the document.getElementById statements as

```
document.getElementById(value + "1").value=num;
document.getElementById(value + "2").value=num1;
```

Please check jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TbGcD/1/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, something like this should provide decent performance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <script>
        function start()
        {
            var ids = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
            var id1s = [1,2,3,4,5];
            var id2s = [6,7,8,9,10];
            var table= document.getElementById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                alert("Showing assignment of values");
                table.innerHTML+= '<tr><td>'+ids[i]+'</td><td>'+id1s[i]+'</td><td>'+id2s[i]+'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="start()">Display</button>
    <table id="tableId" border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr>
            <td>Variable</td> 
            <td>Value1</td>
            <td>Value2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

If you don't need to see each row assigned separately, I suggest doing something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <script>
        function start()
        {
            var ids = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
            var id1s = [1,2,3,4,5];
            var id2s = [6,7,8,9,10];
            var table= document.getElementById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var text='';

            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                text+='<tr><td>'+ids[i]+'</td><td>'+id1s[i]+'</td><td>'+id2s[i]+'</td></tr>';
            }
            table.innerHTML+= text;
            text='';
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="start()">Display</button>
    <table id="tableId" border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr>
            <td>Variable</td> 
            <td>Value1</td>
            <td>Value2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. the only thing was that the second and third column was supposed to be text boxes. Now i am able to do that by a reply from saju in this thread...